# Does VPN offer 100% security?

Tags: vpn

If log in to Amazon website using VPN does this offer 100% security and hide static IP address? OR does some data leak through and show , making Amazon suspicious?

Comment: What do you mean by "100% security" ??

Comment: why would amazon be suspicious?

Comment: My guess would be they are planning to do something fraudulent, and want to know if a VPN would help them get away with it.

Answer (score 6):

No. Nothing offers 100% security and a VPN is no exception. For example a VPN will not magically protect you if you connect to a malicious site serving malware. A properly configured VPN will hide your public IP address though from the party you connect to, but won't prevent the site from identifying you for example by using [browser fingerprinting techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_fingerprint) or by tracking you over multiple visits. And a VPN can actually make Amazon or others suspicious: the use of a VPN can often be detected by the server you connect to and some might consider using a VPN suspicious.